# Right Ident on Right Justified text changes bottom border in Apple Pages

Tags: macos, iwork-pages

I'm trying to add spacing on right justified text without changing the bottom border using the most recent version of Apple Pages.

If you change the left ident it just moves the text in, but if you change the right ident, it moves the border in as well.

Is there any way to achieve having the border go all the way across with a right ident and text justified to the right?

[image: left and right ident example]